# Taking data as observable , modify and store changes in local array

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following stored in a local JSON file

```
[
  {
    "username": "zero",
    "id": 0,
    "firstName": "a",
    "lastName": "b"
  },
  {
    "username": "one",
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "c",
    "lastName": "d"
  }
]
```

and an array `this.users` of type `User[]` (interface) in my class.
How can I create a function `delete(username)` that removes the item with the corresponding username and returns the modifications inside `this.users` using observables?

Comment: Why do you want to use observables?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```js
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

users = [
  { "username": "zero", "id": 0, "firstName": "a", "lastName": "b" },
  { "username": "one", "id": 1, "firstName": "c",  "lastName": "d" }
];

deleteUser(username: string): Observable<any> {
  let index = this.users.findIndex((user: any) => user.username === username);
  if(index != -1) this.users.splice(index,1);
  return of(this.users);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate the users array after hitting the api in service and then save a copy in the local service instance (or sessionStorage if you want to persist data on page refresh). Now, assuming that you have got the data in the users array in `YourService`, create a new method `deleteUsername` in the same service file.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class YourService {
   
   public users: User[];

   constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

   getUsers() {
     // Get your user data here using http.get hit and subscribe to get data in the users array..
   }


   deleteUsername(userId: number): Observable<User[]> {
     // Ideally you should hit API via _http.delete to delete the user from db.
     // Since, in your case, it is just a local modification of the array that you want, below implementation should work just as fine.

      // Make a copy of the users received from getUsers method above.
      // NOTE: The deep copy doesn't work for nested objects.

      const usersCopy: User[] = [...this.users];

      const indexOfUserYouWantToDelete = usersCopy.findIndex(user => user.id === userId);

      if (indexOfUserYouWantToDelete > -1) {
         usersCopy.splice(idx, 1);
      }

      // If you do not want to modify the original users Array
      return of(usersCopy);

      // Comment above return statement as you below one 
      // if you need to modify existing users Array
    
      this.users = usersCopy;

      return of(this.users);
   }
}
```

The above should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to use rxjs filter and toArray operators to filter out the items and emit one filtered array using toArray operator.

```
delete(username: string) {
    from(this.users)
      .pipe(
        filter(user => user.username !== username),
        toArray()
      )
      .subscribe(users => {
        this.users = users;
      });
```

Here is the example:-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wgnbtc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts